# how to change the x of view in relativelayout in android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

i have a view in relativeleayout , I want to change the place of the view to the middle of  relativeleayout:
what is the problém

```
     RelativeLayout partieoption = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.partieoption);
        int wpartieoption =partieoption.getWidth();
     int hpartieoption = partieoption.getHeight();
      ImageView x = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo2);
      x.setX( (float) ( hpartieoption/2 ) );
```

the xml :

```
                    android:id="@+id/partieoption"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:weightSum="6"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >




                        <ImageView 
                            android:id="@+id/photo2"
                            android:src="@drawable/loglog"
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            />




               </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You really should not be using setX and setY for anything other than temporary animations.  THe correct way of centering a view horizontally in to add android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't be using a view.  Moving views is EXTREMELY computationally expensive.

Comment: What's the solution ?

Comment: Really depends on exactly what you're doing, which you didn't describe.  But I really doubt you need to do it programatically, since your code above would be no different than using layout_centerHorizontal.  And if you do you're probably using the wrong technique entirely.  So what are you doing that makes you think you need that?